# Class 'ARCollaborationData' disallows secure coding

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, multipeer-connectivity, nssecurecoding

I have an app that offers collaboration in AR and I was following the docs on how to send `ARSession.CollaborationData` using `MultipeerConnectivity`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration/3152987-iscollaborationenabled

It appears that, with iOS 14, this is no longer possible. I receive the following error when I try to unarchive:

> Class 'ARCollaborationData' disallows secure coding. It must return
> YES from supportsSecureCoding.

I'm more or less using the exact some code as given in the documentation and it worked flawlessly with iOS 13. Now, with iOS 14, I am not sure how to fix this issue. I've tried sending it with `requiringSecureCoding: false` as well as trying to create an `NSKeyedUnarchiver` which has `requiresSecureCoding` set to false as well. As far as I'm aware, I'm not able to change the implementation of `NSSecureCoding` for `ARSession.CollaborationData` (which is supposedly present anyway).

This is the code that sends the data:

```
guard let encodedData = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(
    withRootObject: data,
    requiringSecureCoding: true
)
else { fatalError("Unexpectedly failed to encode collaboration data.") }
// Use reliable mode if the data is critical, and unreliable mode if the data is optional.
let dataIsCritical = data.priority == .critical
try session.send(
    encodedData,
    toPeers: session.connectedPeers,
    with: dataIsCritical ? .reliable : .unreliable
)
```

And I decode everything by calling this function:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ARSession.CollaborationData.self, from: data)
```

Has anyone else had this issue before? Could it be that this is a bug and I just have to report it and wait? Either way, thanks in advance for any hints or tips :) They are greatly appreciated!

Best regards,
Bjoern